# Can I cache "external" images in a PWA?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-cache, progressive-web-apps, web-worker

I'm using images in a PWA that are hosted outside the PWA web site. Can I still convince the web worker to cache them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as the third party resources have enabled CORS.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/addAll#Exceptions

Comment: I want to use images stored on Google Photos. It works online (with occasional 403, which I don't understand), but they are not cashed. The PWA uses the standard web worker from Google Developers. Is this a CORS problem? Or should I try to dive into the web worker.js? (My gut feeling is to just leave it to them since things are not stable yet.)

Comment: I would first ensure that you are requesting to cache the right resource, then log the request and response. If you notice that the proper CORS response headers are set, then use the Cache API to verify that the resource has been cached. If it _has_ been cached, then ensure that you are using a cache first strategy in your service worker.